# Преобразование данных полученныз через сокеты

Tags: python

нужна помощь, я получаю данные через сокеты и вывожу его след кодом

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'    # The remote host
PORT = 23456              # The same port as used by the server

client = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,
)

client.connect(
    (HOST, PORT)
)

while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

вывод полученных данных через сокет

```
 2020.12.02 10:47:28.819: Ask = 13332.0, Bid = 13331.5, Volume = 2, Last = 13331.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 2.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5
```

Данные приходят в формате str. Немогу разобраться в одном. Как разбить строку на отдельные данные и записать их в csv по колонкам и строкам. Как реализовать это все?

Comment: так проблема не с сокетами, а с парсингом строки? Похоже обычного `s.split(',')` будет достаточно

Comment: там немного другие преобразования нужны, обычный спит не поможет

Comment: могу в несколько спилтов, могу регуляркой. Вопрос то был не в этом

Comment: может есть какой-то пример кода?

Comment: вот ниже привели вполне рабочий и хороший пример.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "2020.12.02 10:47:28.819: Ask = 13332.0, Bid = 13331.5, Volume = 2, Last = 13331.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 2.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5"

res = dict()

pos = text.rfind(':')
res['time'] = text[:pos]

for data in text[pos + 1:].split(","):
    obj = data.split("=")
    res[obj[0]] = obj[1]

print(res)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь выводится одна и та же строка с каждым получением сообщения из сокета

Comment: 2020.12.02 10:47:28.819: Ask = 13332.0, Bid = 13331.5, Volume = 2, Last = 13331.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 2.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5"

Comment: и так раз 50 ... а поступающие сообщения не обрабатываются

Comment: вы это серьезно пишите?
первая строчка в моем коде исключительно для тестирования, я же ничего из сокетов не получаю - удалите ее и работайте с тем, что вам выдает сокет

Comment: я понял что вы не работаете с сокетами, я просто не могу понять как применить ваш код ко входящим сообщениям..

Comment: ну как я понял вы привели строку входящего сообщения в которой содержатся данные, которые надо распарсить - я привел код который их распарсивает в словарь - разве не это нужно? Т.е. на входе должно быть `text = data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: как раз то что я и искал, буду искать способ его применить, Спасибо!

Comment: Ваш вариант вполне рабочий, одно но

Comment: res[obj[0]] = obj[1]    из-за этой строки ошибка вылетает

Comment: сделайте print(obj) И посмотрите что выданется, а лучше полную строку запроса
я написал парсер для конкретного вида строки, если лезет что-то в другом формате - это тоже надо учитывать, судя по ошибке - подозреваю, что лезет obj только с 1 элементом - это надо учесть значит

Comment: ну да , она возвращает такой словарь

Comment: ['Hello\r\n']
[' Ask ', ' 13308.5']
[' Bid ', ' 13307.5']
[' Volume ', ' 1']
[' Last ', ' 13307.5']
[' Flag ', ' 88']
[' Volume Real ', ' 1.0']
[' Type ', ' Sell']
[' Spread ', ' 10\n\r\n']

Comment: где Hello это ответ сервера

Comment: только не в строку а в столбец

Comment: тогда надо понимать вообще все возможные варианты вывода и лишь потом уже можно будет сказать как правильно написать парсер